# Unable to resolve file from node_modules

Tags: angular, webpack, node-modules

I'm using NGX-Highlight which in turns uses HighlightJS, in order to present in a good looking way some JSON files to end users.

I followed the instruction to import and then to use the library.

In a pure Angular project the problem im posting here does not occur, and everything just runs smoothly. So this tells me that imports and code are good.

The application in which im working on, uses Webpack and im gussing that this is the problem but i can figure it out how to solve it.

Here is the problem:

```
import { HighlightModule } from 'ngx-highlightjs';

import xml from 'highlight.js/lib/languages/xml';
import scss from 'highlight.js/lib/languages/scss';
import typescript from 'highlight.js/lib/languages/typescript';

export function hljsLanguages() {
    return [
       {name: 'typescript', func: typescript},
       {name: 'scss', func: scss},
       {name: 'xml', func: xml}
    ];
}
```

xml, scss, and typescript are undefined.

As i said, i think the problem is Webpack due to the fact of the path required to get to the library files: 'highlight.js/lib/languages/xml';

That "highligth.js" i think is broking the path for webpack.

Is there a way i can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 'highlight.js/lib/languages/xml/
try using the module webpack path

```
import xml from 'ngx-highlightjs/lib/languages/xml'
```

It might be it

Comment: The problem you have is that you're trying to make a directory out of a file since highlight.js is a file not a directory. So there shouldn't be problem with broken lib but with the path you're reffering to.

Comment: Have you tried something just like this? `import { xml } from 'ngx-highlightjs';`

Comment: highlight.js is a directory not a file, thats the point! webpack thinks its a file (im gussing)

Comment: import { xml } from 'ngx-highlightjs'; does not works because ngx-highlight is 
 something different from highlightjs.